# Handle "POSIXt" objects in ggvis with bar plot

Tags: r, plot, time, bar-chart, ggvis

Considering the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(t=seq(as.POSIXct('2010-01-01 00:15:00'),as.POSIXct('2010-01-01 24:00:00'),by='15 min'),
                 y=rnorm(96,50.10))
```

I want to produce a ggvis bar plot with `t` on the x-axis showing only `%H:%M` and `y` on the y-axis. So I used the following code:

```
library(ggvis)
df %>% ggvis(x=~t,y=~y) %>% 
  layer_bars() %>%
  dd_axis(type="x",format="%H:%M",title = 'Time')
```

It gave me an error:`Error in Math.POSIXt(x) : 'abs' not defined for "POSIXt" objects`. It seems that `layer_bars()` cannot deal with `"POSIXt"` objects? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could format your data before calling ggvis

```
df$t<- format(df$t,"%H:%M")
```

For your example, this gives a horrible graph. Perhaps it works better on your real case.